# using css to show hide content given its id

Tags: css

with only css, how would one show/hide a div knowing its id?

with jQuery it would have been simple and even simpler with vanilla javascript, but how to do this with just css?

the checkbox hack needs to have a specific structure to work

also, I'd like it to only hide the div before the next h1, if there were any.

```css
label:after {
  content: " [show]";
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

p {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none; 
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + div {
  display: block;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label:after {
  content: " [hide]"
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Vampires and Vegetarians 
  <label for="Vampires_and_Vegetarians"></label>
</h1>
<input type="checkbox" id="Vampires_and_Vegetarians">
<div id="Vampires_and_Vegetarians">
  <p>Content for Vampires and Vegetarians</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Which element are you trying to show / hide? And under what circumstances should it be shown / hidden?

Comment: Your example currently has a duplicate ID (two elements with `id="Vampires_and_Vegetarians"`) which will stop anything being able to refer reliably to that ID.

Comment: Your label is not a sibling of the input so `~` will not work here.

Answer (score 2):

In order for your checkbox to control things, it has to appear before it in the `dom` so I've moved it to the very top.

I've also changed your CSS a little, you were hiding the `p` and then trying to show the `div` now we're hiding the `div` then showing it.

I've also changed you `+` to a `~` as the `div` was not a direct sibling.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~h1 label:after {
  content: " [hide]"
}

label:after {
  content: " [show]";
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

input[type=checkbox]~div {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Vampires_and_Vegetarians">
  <h1>
    Vampires and Vegetarians
    <label for="Vampires_and_Vegetarians"></label>
  </h1>
  <div id="Vampires_and_Vegetarians">
    <p>Content for Vampires and Vegetarians</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Zombies_and_Zucchini">
  <h1>
    Zombies and Zucchini
    <label for="Zombies_and_Zucchini"></label>
  </h1>
  <div id="Zombies_and_Zucchini">
    <p>Content for Zombies and Zucchini</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

I hope you find this helpful 
Feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: thanks. what about if there were more headers and divs after the first one? how do I make it only hide just the div before the next header?

Comment: I've edited the code, wrapping the code in another `div` does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the hierarchy of the elements here like below. Because `~` is used to target the next siblings elements not the previous one. Also don't use the same id twice

```css
label:after {
  content: " [show]";
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~.content {
  display: block;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~h1 label:after {
  content: " [hide]"
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="1">
  <h1>
    1
    <label for="1"></label>
  </h1>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Content for 1</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="2">
  <h1>
    2
    <label for="2"></label>
  </h1>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Content for 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. what about if there were more headers and divs after the first one? how do I make it only hide just the div before the next header?

Comment: @totalnoob just wrap your whole block into a div. Check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Id cannot be used twice in the same page. read-
https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Your code is right but the structure was slightly wrong. See my snippet below

```css
label:after {
  content: " [show]";
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

div {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none; 
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label ~ div {
  display: block;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label:after {
  content: " [hide]"
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="Vampires_and_Vegetarians">
<label for="Vampires_and_Vegetarians">Vampires and Vegetarians</label>
<div><p>Content for Vampires and Vegetarians</p></div>
```

Hope this helps :)

> **UPDATE AFTER READING PO COMMENT**
>
> In case you have more divs to show and hide content through checkbox,
>   you just need to apply a **unique id** to every div. That's it. :)

see below example

```css
label:after {
  content: " [show]";
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

section {
  display:block;
  margin-top:20px;
}

div {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none; 
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label ~ div {
  display: block;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label:after {
  content: " [hide]"
}
```

```html
<section>
<input type="checkbox" id="Vampires_and_Vegetarians1">
<label for="Vampires_and_Vegetarians1">Vampires and Vegetarians 1</label>
<div><p>Content for Vampires and Vegetarians 1</p></div>
</section>

<section>
<input type="checkbox" id="Vampires_and_Vegetarians2">
<label for="Vampires_and_Vegetarians2">Vampires and Vegetarians 2</label>
<div><p>This is 2nd para</p></div>
</section>

<section>
<input type="checkbox" id="Vampires_and_Vegetarians3">
<label for="Vampires_and_Vegetarians3">Vampires and Vegetarians 3</label>
<div><p>This is 3rd para</p></div>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks. what about if there were more headers and divs after the first one? how do I make it only hide just the div before the next header?